# Cannot get only number of hits in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Im using _msearch api to send multiple queries to elastic.
I only need to know how many hits generates each query.
What I understood, you can use the `size` parameter by setting it to "0" in order to only get the count. However, I still get results with all the found documents. Here is my query:

```
{"index":"myindex","type":"things","from":0,,"size":0}
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match_all":{}}],"must_not":[],{"match": 
{"firstSearch":true}}]}}}, "size" : 0}
{"index":"myindex","type":"things","from":0,,"size":0}
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match_all":{}}],"must_not":[],{"match": 
{"secondSearch":true}}]}}}, "size" : 0}
```

Im using curl to get the results, this way:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XGET localhost:9200/_msearch?pretty=1 --data-binary "@requests"; echo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting size as zero signifies that you are asking Elasticsearch to return all the documents which satisfies the query.

You can let Elasticsearch know that you do not need the documents by sending "_source" as false.

Example:

```
{
  "query": {},
  "_source": false,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`GET /indexname/type/_count? 
{ "query":
 { "match_all": {} }
}`

please read more document: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html

Comment: But this is a multiple search. I understood that you can do this for ordinary searches.